# Desired sheet not being activated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code involves three spreadsheets

1. The spreadsheet the code is in
2. An source spreadsheet referred to as `unstructuredSheets`
3. A target spreadsheet referred to as `structuredSpreadsheet`.

The instruction `structuredSheet.activate` doesn't seem to do anything. The first sheet in the `structuredSpreadsheet` remains active.
Any ideas why that would be?

```
function     importUnstructuredSpreadsheet2(unstructuredId,structuredId){
    //this function uses copy/paste

        var ssUnstructured=SpreadsheetApp.openById(unstructuredId);
        var numUnstructuredSheets= ssUnstructured.getSheets().length;  


    var ssStructured=SpreadsheetApp.openById(structuredId ); 
    var numStructuredSheets= ssStructured.getSheets().length;
    for (var n = 0; n < numUnstructuredSheets ; n++ ) {



     var unstructuredSheets=ssUnstructured.getSheets();
     var unstructuredSheet= unstructuredSheets[n];
     var structuredSheets=  ssStructured.getSheets();

     sheetName=unstructuredSheet.getSheetName();

     var usedRange =  unstructuredSheet.getDataRange(); 
     var structuredSheet=ssStructured.getSheetByName(sheetName);

     structuredSheet.activate();
     structuredSheet.getRange('A1').activate();// may want to do at starting cell
     unstructuredSheet.usedRange.copyTo(structuredSheets.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS, false);
   }//each sheet
```

Comment: Are the three sheets sharing the same Id? If they have three different Ids you could do it with SpreadsheetApp.openById("id"). Also, where is the variable ssStructured coming from?

Comment: @Jescanellas In the above code I added the code that precedes the for loop.

Comment: @Jescanellas to clarify: 3 spreadsheets, not 3 sheets. 3 different ids.- target spreadsheet and source spreadsheet each have multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1):

`activate` only works on scripts that ran over spreadsheets that are opened by a user by using the Google Sheets UI not by spreadsheets opened by code.

Comment: Thanks.. That sounds like the reason.